# PyMongo search in db

Tags: python, pymongo

I have post document in database:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5982f3240273810378f60b00"
},
"context": "",
"date": {
    "day": "03",
    "month": "08",
    "min": "55",
    "hour": "11",
    "year": "2017"
},
"title": "title",
"category": "it" }
```

and I want to find posts that has data -> year 2017, so I tried something like this:

```
test = dbController.get_collection('posts').find({'date': {'year' : '2017'}})
```

but it doesn't work, does exist any kind of method to fix that?

Comment: try `dbController.get_collection('posts').find({'date.year' : '2017'})` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dbController.get_collection('posts').find({'date.year' : '2017'})
```